# How I can convert TypeScript to JavaScript with @type angular compiler cli manually

Tags: json, angular, angular-compiler-cli

I want to run `ngc` (angular compiler-CLI) manually to convert TypeScript to JavaScript code.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "first-angular2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {

  }
}
```

added `typescript`, `@type`, `angular` dependencies

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOption" : {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
        },
        "types": [
        "node",
        "source-map",
        "uglify-js",
        "webpack"
        ]
        },
          "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "dist"
        ],
          "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
            "forkChecker": true,
            "useWebpackText": true
        },
        "compileOnSave": false,
        "buildOnSave": false,
      "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": ".",
        "debug": true
      }
}
```

configuration about typescript to convert on javascript

**Error :**

```
root@VSS-DT0086:/var/www/angular2/first-angular2# ./node_modules/.bin/ngc -m
Error: Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts:88:123: Cannot find name 'Map'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts:88:165: Cannot find name 'Map'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts:12:17: Cannot find name 'Map'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts:13:17: Cannot find name 'Set'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts:16:18: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:24:15: Cannot find name 'Map'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:28:16: Cannot find name 'Map'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts:53:49: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts:61:65: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:10:66: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:66:60: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:66:70: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:106:67: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:122:101: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:148:67: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:150:101: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts:14:34: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts:28:25: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts:8:53: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:369:30: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:415:30: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:416:20: Cannot find name 'Set'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:417:15: Cannot find name 'Set'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:418:246: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts:427:63: Cannot find name 'Set'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts:13:23: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts:26:18: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts:27:46: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts:38:72: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts:40:74: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.d.ts:62:18: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts:18:32: Cannot find name 'Map'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts:32:87: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts:49:9: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts:44:49: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts:46:65: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts:10:23: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    at check (/var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:31:15)
    at Tsc.typeCheck (/var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:86:9)
    at /var/www/angular2/first-angular2/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:33:23
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
Compilation failed
```